# Canot load header php file's style and script

Tags: php

This is how my header.php looks like;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="headerStyle.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="headerScript.js"></script>
<?php

if( strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index') ){
    echo '<title>My website title</title>';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">';
    echo '<script src="index.js"></script>';
}
if( strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'index') ){
    echo '<title>Contact Us</title>';
}//And goes on like this..

?>

</head>
```

header.php,headerStyle.css,headerScript.js are in same folder : mysite/header/

And this how my index.php looks like;

```
<?php 
include 'header/header.php';  
    //And some other irrelevant stuff (<body> etc.)
?>
```

My index file's path is mysite/

The problem is when I view the index page it cannot load headerStyle.css and headerScript.js.

What is the best way to manage that?I'm trying to make a solid,dynamic header.php so i can include it for every page in my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a constant and make use of `__DIR__` magic constant.

```
define('HEADER',__DIR__.'/');

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo HEADER; ?>headerStyle.css">
<script src="<?php echo HEADER; ?>headerScript.js"></script>
```